# timeout на perl как в новых coreutils

Tags: bash, perl

Пытаюсь сделать скрипт аналогичный `/usr/bin/timeout` в coreutils (т.к. на сервере centos5, апгрейдить нельзя)

Есть такой скрипт:

**timeout.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $PID=$$;
my $timeout=shift;
my @args=@ARGV;

my $pid = fork();
defined $pid or die "fork: $!";
$pid == 0 && exec(@args);

my $timed_out = 0;
$SIG{ALRM} = sub { $timed_out = 1; die; };
alarm $timeout;
eval { waitpid $pid, 0 };
alarm 0;
if ($timed_out) {
    print "Timed out!\n";
    kill 9, $pid;    
    kill 9, $PID;
}
elsif ($@) {
    warn "error: $@\n";
}
```

тестируем:

**хорошо**

```
$ time ./timeout.pl 2 sleep 6
Timed out!
Убито

real    0m2.012s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time a=`./timeout.pl 2 sleep 6`

real    0m2.009s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.008s
```

**плохо**

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/sh
a=`./timeout.pl 2 ./run_script.sh`

$ cat run_script.sh 
#!/bin/sh
sleep 6

$ time ./test.sh

real    0m6.015s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s
```

вопрос: почему так и как исправить ?

**SIGTERM** посылать тоже пробовал, оно вообще в `if ($timed_out)` не заходит.

Comment: @eicto не в того стреляете. Вы убиваете процесс `run_script.sh`, который даже и не шевелится, а думаете, что убиваете `sleep`

Выведите на печать $pid и список процессов `system('ps')` перед `alarm $timeout`

Comment: кусок `ps xawwwf`

    12109 pts/2    Ss     0:01  \_ /bin/bash
    14236 pts/2    S+     0:00  |   \_ /bin/sh ./test.sh
    14238 pts/2    S+     0:00  |   |   \_ /usr/bin/perl ./timeout.pl 2 ./run_script.sh
    14239 pts/2    S+     0:00  |   |       \_ /bin/sh ./run_script.sh
    14241 pts/2    S+     0:00  |   |       |   \_ sleep 6
    14240 pts/2    R+     0:00  |   |       \_ ps -xawwf

главное во всем этом то, что используя /usr/bin/timeout все что надо работает, включая exitcode от run_script.sh

Comment: Могет быть, могет быть. Проснётся кто-нибудь грамотный -- напишет. А так -- прибивайте sleep. Если нужно, чтобы он запускался под pid run_script.sh, то запускайте его через exec:

      #!/bin/sh
      exec sleep 6

А насчёт "должен погибнуть" -- так он и погибает. В своё время.

Comment: дело не в sleep, там сложный скрипт, который надо прибить по timeout, если я так напишу, то следующее вложение даст тот-же результат.

Comment: Попробуйте удержаться от суицида. Жизнь может быть прекрасной

(Это я в смысле -- убрать

      kill 9, $PID

). Ну и wait лучше не забывать.

Comment: там надо killtree организовывать, в общем я решил с IPC:CMD, но пока не уверен что на centos воткнется... ставлю с rpmforge (как я ненавижу всё это редхатное,  и кто решил, что это типа стандарт... )

Comment: а что не понятно ? 

 * почему работает ? 
 ** это в вопросе есть
 * куда делись 2 микросекунды ? 
 ** на запуск наверное

Comment: >используя /usr/bin/timeout все что надо работает

Собственно, timeout и делает то же самое: alarm+execvp. С одним отличием: не kill(pid, term_signal), а kill(0, term_signal). Ergo, не 9, а -9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@klopp](/users/6550/klopp)](/users/6550/klopp) да.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $PID=$$;
my $timeout=shift;
my @args=@ARGV;
setpgrp;

my $pid = fork();
defined $pid or die "fork: $!";
$pid == 0 && exec(@args);

my $timed_out = 0;
$SIG{ALRM} = sub { $timed_out = 1; die; };
#system('ps');
alarm $timeout;
eval { waitpid $pid, 0 };
alarm 0;
if ($timed_out) {
    print "Timed out!\n";
    kill 15, 0;
}
elsif ($@) {
    warn "error: $@\n";
}
```

[[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) а непонятно мне было в комментариях к вопросу -- глаз замылился. Не увидел, что вызываю команду sleep прямо в ком. строке.

Comment: Ага, именно. Тут, правда, одна побочка может вылезать, системное сообщение о завершении (убийстве) процесса. Но это лечится просто:

    $SIG{ALRM} = sub { $timed_out = 1; die; };
    $SIG{СИГНАЛ} = 'IGNORE';

Comment: ну если работает - хорошо, exitcode правда все равно не получить, так-что через IPC лучше

Comment: А так? Уже в порядке бреда :)

    use IPC::Open2;
    use IO::Select;
    
    open2 my $out, my $in, 'запускаемое' or die $!;
    my $io = IO::Select->new($out);
    
    if($io->can_read(таймаут)) 
    {
    # уря!
    } 
    else 
    {
        kill 15, 0;
    }

Comment: ну так уже IPC юзается, какой смысл если у IPC:Cmd есть timeout. (не проверял код)

Comment: @klopp Вы уверены, что Вам не требуется помощь психиатра? Маньяк, однако.
Использовать my в параметрах вызываемой функции -- точно маньяк.

Comment: Я маньяк, но мирный и тихий :) Да, здесь только схема, была бы она обёрнута в if() - было бы всё законно.

Answer (score 0):

реализовал через IPC::Cmd:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict;
use IPC::Cmd qw(run_forked);
my $timeout=shift;
my $stdout;
my $hashref = run_forked(@ARGV, { timeout => $timeout});
print $hashref->{'stdout'};
print STDERR $hashref->{'stderr'}; 
if ($hashref->{'timeout'}) {            
        print STDERR "Timed out!\n";
        exit 142;
}
exit $hashref->{'exit_code'};
```

*аргументы команды надо экранировать (`./timeout.pl 1 "sleep 100"`), (некогда сейчас делать чтобы нормально работало);*

для этого пришлось ставить модуль через rpmforge. если кто знает решение попроще, welcome!

Comment: отвечу здесь, так как дурацкое ограничение
@klopp - я пробовал term и прочее, почему-то не убивается по alarm от того и спросил кстати у timeout есть:

    -s, --signal=СИГНАЛ
                   задать сигнал, который будет послан по таймауту.
                   СИГНАЛ может задаваться именем, например HUP или номером.
                   Список сигналов см. по команде kill -l

Comment: Какой сигнал слать неважно, важно что timeout шлёт сигнал не процессу, а группе kill(**0**,...).